# Different levels logging to different places

Tags: go, logging, logstash

I am implementing logging mechanism for one service I am writing in Go. We are using logrus library since it is popular and is being supported regularly. I want to know if it's possible to have different levels (INFO, DEBUG, WARNING, FATAL) log to different places (Slack, Logstash...) by defining multiple hooks, and pass an argument for verbosity to redirect all the logs to stdout

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried? Are you having specific trouble?

Comment: @Flimzy I only managed to output all logs to one place. Do I need to instantiate multiple logrus instances to handle logging to different places?

Comment: You need to add multiple hooks. Please refer to the documentation--Logrus is very well documented. And if you have specific problems, then of course feel free to ask here (with examples of your code).